# Nginx redirects and 301

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails

I have a ruby on rails app that's I want to force ssl on one path `/accounts` and `http` for the rest of the app. My current Nginx configuration is as follow

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    root /home/ubuntu/deploy/app_location/public;

    location / {
      rewrite  ^ http://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location /accounts {
       rewrite  ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }
    location ^~ /assets/ {
      gzip_static on;
      expires max;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;

#rewrite (.*) https://$server_name$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ...ssl stuff



  resolver 8.8.8.8;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";

    root /home/ubuntu/deploy/app_location/public;

     location / {
       rewrite  ^ http://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
       }

    location /accounts {
    }

    location ^~ /assets/ {
      gzip_static on;
      expires max;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        #proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Nginx keeps redirecting and not going to the root of the app, what Am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have two server blocks with the same port and server name. `nginx` should warn about this if you test the configuration with `nginx -t`.

Comment: You don't want to have a setup with `http` content now, since Chrome will start warning about all http sites next year.

Comment: So any suggestion on how to resolve this?